# IntentService.onDestroy() not called when Activity is closed

Tags: java, android

I have an `IntentService` as follows which does a few queue-able long running tasks which should not be killed. I'm using an `IntentService` as opposed to `Service` since `IntentService` handles the threading and queuing of incoming intents which is desirable. In order to keep the service running, I'm acquiring a wake lock and setting the service to be foreground with `setForeground(int, Notification)` within `onCreate()` and this is reversed in `onDestroy()` where I release these resources.

Unfortunately, while `onCreate()` is always called when the `IntentService` is first created, `onDestroy()` is only occasionally called. I have so far figured that `onDestroy()` is only called when I leave the main activity of my application running. Once I remove the activity (close the window) and lock the phone, the tasks allocated to the service continue to completion, but `onDestroy()` is never called, resulting in wake lock and notification persisting.

This is what I have for my `IntentService`:

```
public class BackupBackgroundService extends IntentService {
    // ...variables

    public BackupBackgroundService() {
        super("BackupBackgroundService");
        setIntentRedelivery(true);
    }

    private NotificationCompat.Builder getNotification(String id) { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Syncopoli: Sync wakelock");
        wakeLock.acquire(20 * 60 * 1000); // timeout in millis

        Notification notif = /* ... */;
        startForeground(App.SYNC_NOTIF_ID, notif);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopForeground(true);
        wakeLock.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent work) {
        /* do time-intensive task in blissful ignorance */
    }

}
```

I have excluded parts for brevity.

My question now is: how do I go about reliably acquiring and releasing resources before and after `onHandleIntent` (respectively) when working with `IntentService`?

I have thought of two solutions for this issue:
1. acquire resources at the beginning of `onHandleIntent` and release them at the end, and let android destroy the service at its leisure.
2. reimplement `IntentService` by using `Service` directly and add the lifecycle management parts on top.

I'm hoping there is a better way to do this than constantly re/acquiring resources and reimplementing `IntentService`.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad Almost everything you said in there is wrong.  onDestroy is called whenever an Activity is destroyed, except when its destroyed abnormally as part of termination of the application.  It is frequently used for releasing resources.  onStop also is always called except in abnormal termination.  Please take time to study the android lifecycle and framework before passing off incorrect information like this.  You are utterly wrong on the differences between pause/stop/destroy and when to use each.

Comment: @GabeSechan Oh well, I take my words back.